# Sentry on Symfony: how to exclude `NotFoundHttpException`

Tags: php, symfony, logging, sentry

I'm using the SentryBundle to integrate Sentry in my Symfony app.

I don't want to record "NotFoundExceptions", so I configured the bundle this way:

```yaml
sentry:
    dsn: '%env(SENTRY_DSN)%'
    register_error_listener: false # Disables the ErrorListener
    monolog:
        error_handler:
            enabled: true
            level: error
    messenger:
        enabled: true # flushes Sentry messages at the end of each message handling
        capture_soft_fails: true # captures exceptions marked for retry too
    options:
        environment: '%kernel.environment%'
#        release: '%env(VERSION)%' #your app version
        excluded_exceptions:
            - Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
```

Unfortunately, this seems to be not sufficient as the exceptions continue to be logged in Sentry.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you set the sentry handler in the monolog config as written in the [doc](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-symfony#optional-use-monolog-handler-provided-by-sentrysentry-available-since-320)? and you could exclude specific http error codes there as well: `excluded_http_codes: [403, 404, { 400: ['^/foo', '^/bar'] }]`

Comment: Yes, analyzing deeper the log in Sentry, I noted this and I suspected it was logged by Monolog. The strange thing is that in Monolog I already exclude 404 errors... I'll give another look: thank you!

Comment: Hi, did you find another solution?

Comment: I didn't investigate this further... I'll do in the next days... I will try this:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        sentry:
            type: service
            id: Sentry\Monolog\Handler
            excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
```

Comment: Sorry for the wrong formatting... Basically I will add the key `exclude_http_codes` directly to the configuration of Sentry in Monolog config.

Comment: If you try this config, please, let me know if it works!

Answer (score 6):

For the recent versions of Sentry and Sentry bundle (version 4) you need to create an entry for the `Sentry\Integration\IgnoreErrorsIntegration` service.

Update your `services.yaml` with:

```
services:

    <...other services>

    Sentry\Integration\IgnoreErrorsIntegration:
        arguments:
            $options:
                ignore_exceptions:
                    - Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
```

After that to tell Sentry to use this integration you need to update your `sentry.yaml` file to include the `IgnoreErrorsIntegration`:

```
sentry:
    dsn: '%env(SENTRY_DSN)%'
    options:
        integrations:
            - 'Sentry\Integration\IgnoreErrorsIntegration'
```

Source: [changelog of the 4.x branch](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-symfony/commit/a28795fab34784eceb506a61a78a2fcbc58c08a6#diff-1a150f9e2ee0e6cf7cb8864a598cb567dfb617a5e3b0e3310aa947d5f518869a)

Comment: Almost perfect, I've added '@' on the last line of sentry.yaml. It is also in source you mentioned on line 19. Thanks for guidance. It helped me a lot.

Comment: This worked for me. I also found the [official documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/symfony/configuration/symfony-options/#exclude-some-exceptions) to confirm this is the approach recommended by Sentry for Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

As `excluded_exceptions` is not available inside the bundle / sdk anymore and you dont what eg "NotFoundHttpException". you can simply use `excluded_http_codes` with a wrapped monolog handler.

full example

```
sentry:
  register_error_listener: false # custom monolog handler: Disables the ErrorListener to avoid duplicated log in sentry
  dsn: 'FOOBAR_DNS'
  options:
    traces_sample_rate: 0.1
  tracing:
    enabled: true
    dbal:
      enabled: true
      connection: 'default'
    cache:
      enabled: true
    twig:
      enabled: true

# sentry: log also error logs when there is no request exception
monolog:
  handlers:
    sentry:
      type: fingers_crossed
      action_level: error
      handler: sentry_main
      excluded_http_codes: [ 404, 405 ]
      buffer_size: 50
    sentry_main:
      type: sentry
      level: error
      hub_id: Sentry\State\HubInterface
```